# Is using mode and webpack.EnvironmentPlugin redundant?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

Trying to understand what `webpack.EnvironmentPlugin` is doing for me.

is using `mode` and `webpack.EnvironmentPlugin` redundant?

ie

```
module.exports = merge(webpackCommonConfig, {
  mode: 'development',
  ...
  plugins: [
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({ NODE_ENV: 'development' }),
  ],
  ...
});
```

TLDR:
The short answer for this this example only: Yes it's redundant.

Long answer: There is much more going on beyond just saying that mode is changing the env var for NODE_ENV. While at the surface it would look as if `new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({ NODE_ENV: 'development' })` is only doing just that but at runtime.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes for this specific use case only!**

**TL;DR;**

`--mode development` automatically sets:
`process.env.NODE_ENV` to value `development`

`--mode production` automatically sets:
`process.env.NODE_ENV` to value `production`

You don't need to add the following plugin:
`new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({ NODE_ENV: 'development' }),`

This would be the ***only*** setting that would be **redundant**, because `NODE_ENV: 'development|production'` will be automatically set, when using `--mode`!

If you don't set `--mode` it will automatically default to `production`!

**Read on to see why `--mode` is actually not redundant and what it actually does under the hood:**

---

What actually happens if you set `--mode` to `production` or `development`:

**Mode: development**

> Sets `process.env.NODE_ENV` to value `development`.  
>    
> **Enables:** 
>  `NamedChunksPlugin`  
> and `NamedModulesPlugin`.

**Mode: production**

> Sets `process.env.NODE_ENV` to value `production`. 
>  
>   **Enables:** 
>  `FlagDependencyUsagePlugin`,  
> `FlagIncludedChunksPlugin`, 
>   `ModuleConcatenationPlugin`,  
> `NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin`,
>   `OccurrenceOrderPlugin`,  
> `SideEffectsFlagPlugin`  
> and `UglifyJsPlugin`.

`--mode` adds different plugins to the compilation process, depends on which value is set for `mode`.

[>> Reference](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/#mode-development)

> Please remember that setting NODE_ENV doesn't automatically set mode

Comment: what about in the example I used where I'm only setting the NODE_ENV via EnvironmentPlugin. Do I even need to do that if I've already set that via mode?

Comment: No, remove it, it's redundant.

Comment: You can see [here](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/#mode-development) that in development mode, `new webpack.DefinePlugin({ "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify("development") })` is added + `NamedModulesPlugin` + `NamedChunksPlugin`

Comment: Nice thanks, I guess at the surface it was redundant for me, but there is much more happening beyond just saying that mode is setting the env var. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: When using [webpack-merge](https://github.com/survivejs/webpack-merge) to separate DEV and PROD configurations, be careful to not be caught out by the fact that the merging of configuration files happens **before** webpack starts up, and therefore before the NODE_ENV can be set. In this instance I use EnvironmentPlugin also.